# Problem on Wave Function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

A particle of mass $m$ is subjected to a force $F(r) = -\nabla V(r)$ such
that the wave function $\varphi(p, t)$ satisfies the momentum-space Schrödinger
equation

$$\left(\frac{p^2}{2m}-a\Delta^2_p\right) \varphi (p,t) = i\frac{\partial \varphi (p,t)}{ \partial t}$$

where $\hbar = 1$, $a$ is some real constant and

$$\Delta^2_p \equiv \frac{\partial^2 }{ \partial p^2_x} + \frac{\partial^2}{ \partial p^2_y } + \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial^2_z} \, .$$

How do we find force $F(r) \equiv -\nabla V(r)$?

---

We know that the coordinate and momentum representations of a wave function are related by

$$\\psi (r,t) = \left(\frac {1}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac {3}{2}} \int \varphi (k,t) e^{ik\cdot r} \mathrm dk \tag {1}$$

$$\varphi (k,t) = \left(\frac {1}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac {3}{2}} \int \psi (r,t) e^{-ik\cdot r} \mathrm dr \tag {2}$$

where $k \equiv p / \hbar$ with  $Ii  = 1$.

Comment: Could someone take a look? Help is needed.

Comment: I assume you mean $F(r) = -\nabla V(r)$?

Comment: @caverac Yes, I mean that.

Comment: Maybe it would be more useful if you tell us exactly what you're looking for. @Giuseppe already gave you an answer that seems to solve your problem

Comment: @caverac I just want to find an answer which I can get easily. Couldn't work it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(quantum_mechanics)

As you can see, the Schrödinger Hamiltonian operator $H$ can be written as the sum of a kinetic term $T$ and of a potential term $V$. For a system of one particle, the kinetic term takes the form $T=\frac{p^2}{2m}$. Your task is to determine the potential term $V$; once this is done, the force will be given by the formula $F=-\nabla V$.

The first step should be the rewriting of the Schrödinger equation in the following form: 
$$
-i\partial_t \psi = H\psi, $$ 
where $\psi$ is the wavefunction in the position representation. From this you can obtain the explicit expression of $H$, which gives $V$ by the formula $V=H-T$.

The obstruction is the fact that the Schrödinger equation that has been given to you is expressed in the momentum representation. Convert it to the position representation first.

Comment: I've tried it again but could not work it out.

Comment: Could you be more clear?

Comment: @Maxwell: I am sorry, I cannot do the computations now. (Moreover, I think that it would be better for you if you solved the exercise yourself). Transform your equation in the position representation. You will see that one of the terms is exactly the kinetic energy $\hat{T}=-\frac{p^2}{2m}$. The other one will be the potential. Taking the nabla of that term, you get the force.

Comment: can you add it into your answer?

Comment: @Maxwell: it should be clearer now.

Comment: @Guiseppe Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\bf #1}}$

Call 
$$
\vect{q} = \frac{\vect{p}}{\sqrt{2ma}}
$$

such that your can write your equation as

$$
\left(-\frac{1}{2m}\nabla_{\vect{q}}^2 + a\vect{q}^2\right)\phi(\vect{q},t) = -i\partial_t\phi(\vect{q},t)
$$

which is just Schrodinger's equation with a harmonic potential $V(\vect{q}) = a\vect{q}^2$. Solutions to this problems are well known in terms of [Hermite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator) polynomials.

Comment: I did not get what you mean. Could you be more clear?

Comment: @Maxwell Could you tell me exactly where are you getting stuck?

Comment: How did you call $$
\vect{q} = \frac{\vect{p}}{\sqrt{2ma}}
$$? Also If you be more clear about the equation, I'd be happy. It seems like I can do it now.

Comment: Because 

$$
\frac{1}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{q_x^2}} = \frac{1}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{p_x}^2/(2ma)} = a\frac{\partial^2}{\partial p_x^2}
$$

Comment: Shouldn't the potential be $$V(r) = ar^2$$

Comment: @Maxwell This is the same as 

$$
V(q) = aq^2
$$

Comment: The answer is $$V(q) = -aq$$ How did you get that?

Comment: The answer should be $V(q) = -aq$. I think we've found the potential, not force. Then how do we find the force?

Comment: @Maxwell Is that the answer from your textbook?

Comment: Yes, It should be $V(q) = -aq$ But we've the equation which is $F(r) =- \nabla V(r)$

Comment: Can you show it? We already know the potential $V(q) = aq^2$ but It asks the force $F(r)$

Comment: So, the answer is $F(q) = -aq$? or $V(q) = -aq$?

Comment: We've found the potential $V(q) = aq^2$ but the question doesn't want to the potential. Have to find the force and which is given $F(r) = - \nabla  V(r)$ according to my textbook, the answer is $V(r) = -ar$

Comment: How do we take the nable of the term? Can you show it?